# how to set contrast on display

Tags: display

I'm running Kubuntun20.04 on a Dell laptop. How can I increase the contrast on my display? I know how to set gamma and how to set brightness.  Lowering gamma seems to help increase contrast, but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the <kbd>F8</kbd> key while clicking the up (<kbd>↑</kbd>) or the down (<kbd>↓</kbd>) arrow key.

**NB**: I researched that it works.

Comment: I tried it in Kubuntu 21.10.  No luck - it does something with multiple screens.

Comment: I think your method is hardware-dependent, so it will work for some people but not for others.  Often key combinations like that appear as legends on the top row of keys and sometimes at other places on your keyboard.